# Regex Pattern for filtering URLs

Tags: regex

I'm trying to filter a URL using regex and now I have added new portion to the URL so existing regex script won't work.

```
  location ~ ^/p/(?<secure>[\w\-=]+,\d+)(?<file>/.*)$
```

I get $secure , $file values, now I need to get `$user` as well.

Old URL structure:

```
 /p/uwoT4ccBKjBryHxQNrwRzA,1385726761/test.zip
```

New URL structure:

```
 /p/uwoT4ccBKjBryHxQNrwRzA,1385726761,USER/test.zip
```

I've added `,USER` portion to the new URL, how do you do this in regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
location ~ ^/p/(?<secure>[\w\-=]+,\d+),(?<user>[^/]+)(?<file>/.*)$
```

$secure, $file and $user

Comment: Great, THANKS! btw How do you do it?

Comment: `,` is outside `(...)` thus it will not be match.